# How does Java count clicks?

Tags: java, click, mouse

Does anybody know how java counts clicks? and if so where that is documented? I know this is under the hood kind of stuff, but I would like to know what their definitions are.

I found the delay counter for multi click via Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("awt.multiClickInterval")

But, I cannot find what the pixel range is around which mouse movement is allowed and does not reset the counter.  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I understand about MouseEvents.  I do not need to GET this information from Java, I am curious how java decides whether or not there was a multi-click in the first place:
1)Timing is part (addressed above)
2)There is whether or not the mouse moves - how much leeway (in pixels) is given.
3)Potentially another quality that I cannot think of.

I am curious about points 2 & 3

Running Win 8

FURTHER EDIT:
This got a little lost in the weeds.  Ok, so the click itself is an event passed in via the OS.  However, in the MouseEvent generated, there is a .getClickCount() function, which tells you how many clicks have occurred within the time interval specified by awt.multiClickInterval.  There is however a small region around the point of one click that the mouse can move to and click again and still get counted (the mouse does not have to stay exactly on the same pixel).  The question is: What is the maximum number of pixels away from one point that you can click and still have it get counted? This seems like it could not be an OS thing since the interval is an awt property.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain what kind of problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Does it matter? I'm just curious about a language spec..
Not trying to be obnoxious, but it's just a long explanation that really adds nothing to the question.

Comment: It might be the case that it's not Java counting the clicks, but the OS. This might be an OS-specific setting, and the OS just forwards the event to Java.

Comment: If you are curious, this is something else. If you want to solve a *real* problem you are probably on the wrong way...

Comment: I have no doubt that it's specified in a local way (as is the mouse click delay), but I do not know how to find the property that defines that boundary.  I am more than curious, I'm looking at different languages about how they implement click protocols for a project I'm working on.

Comment: Java receives all of its events from the Operating System. So the order would be Hardware -> Operating System -> JVM -> your Java Program. There are ways to get system events at a lower level but not in Java.

Comment: @Tyler Heiks Like the Java selection inside Control Panel? Not seeing where I could find this information in there...

Comment: @AaronMarcus I'm sorry, I don't understand "Like the Java selection inside Control Panel?". The information you are asking about is not surface level "How to Program in Java" information. I do not have any books off-hand I can recommend. However, I think many intro to Java books do discuss the characteristics of the "pass-through" event system that the JVM uses.

Comment: Inside Control Panel in Windows there is usually a 'Java' icon that gives you Java install info, but nothing that low level (that I can find anyways).  Thought by your selection progression Harware->OS->JVM->... you meant I could find it somewhere in there

Comment: @AaronMarcus If you posted the specific problem you are trying to approach we could at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: This is the problem, honest :) I'm designing something, I was curious about hardware interfaces and how this stuff gets handled.  I wanted to know how Java handled it.  It really is just as simple as the question is.

Comment: I just can suggest you to try to measure the double-click region using `java.awt.Robot`. Simulate click, then move mouse and simulate click again. Check `mouseEvent.getClickCount()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events in Java are forwarded from the JVM. The JVM sits on top of an operating system that is forwarded system level events (eg: mouse clicks, key presses, signals, etc.), from the operating system, which are then forwarded to programs running on the JVM (such as a Java program) in an order of priority. Java does not usually make decisions about whether a system level event has occurred (at least not natively).

On ClickCount - this count also comes from the number of click events you receive. The IO reception is dependent on clock cycles. No human will be able to send an amount of IO that the computer can't keep up with. However, when I simulated the click amount with the computer - it stopped being able to measure, with complete accuracy, around 1 IO per 3-4 clock cycles. This is an obscene side case, though. My measurements are completely dependent on my hardware as well so you should take that into account.

The click count is identified by time difference, not pixel distance. I once read that this was distinguished as anything less than 500ms. However, there is no standardized time. The only thing I could find that agreed with me is [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-click).

Edit:
Upon further investigation, there seems to be slight pixel reinforcement based on acceleration of the mouse and distance in pixels. This, however, is very hard to detect and isn't something that you need to rely on heavily. As long as you make a good attempt to double click in about the same place then you should be fine.

Comment: If you are looking to intercept system level events then I suggest you look into a language like C or C++ which is much more suitable for this use.

Comment: Sorry, follow up point which is important.  On multi-clicks (Accessible via getClickCount from an event) do you know how that is actually tabulated by Java (how much pixel drift between clicks is acceptable before the counter is reset)? This would be a java event I would think, not the OS

Comment: and if you have any official documentation backing up your knowledge I would really appreciate a link :) or the appropriate term to search for.

Comment: In the above note - "ability to measure" read "keep up with".

Comment: Interesting note, but not quite what I'm trying to find out..I can move the mouse a very small amount between clicks and still have it 'count' however, if that space gets too big, the counter is reset.  What's that maximum pixel distance? That's what I really need to find out.  See edit to original question as well.

Comment: @AaronMarcus This means that any clicks within 500ms of each other will be considered as part of the same click group until that time passes. However, this is just a generalization. It should be let known that Microsoft tried to get C# to very close to Java when it was first popular so you can imagine that they would they would use similar timings. This is all just a guess, an educated guess, but a guess none the less.

Comment: Yes, the timing part I get, I am curious about pixel distance.  If you click multiple times but move it too much the clickCount is reset.  If you only move a few pixels it is not reset.  I wanna know how many pixels away that boundary is from a click point.

Comment: @AaronMarcus There is no pixel distance limit. It takes time to move your mouse thus it out of the 500ms limit. However, if you move your mouse so many pixels that it is not on the same component or button then it will NOT report as a multi-click.

Comment: Tyler, how do you know that? Not calling into question, just want to verify.

Comment: @AaronMarcus Absolutely, getClickCount() is a method on a mouseEvent. A mouseEvent has an association with a component. If there is a new component then it makes a new mouseEvent.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getClickCount%28%29

Comment: Yes, but how do you know there's no pixel enforcement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56217/discussion-between-tyler-heiks-and-aaron-marcus).